# Most common practice for managing ObjectContext in EF

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm really confused about the standard way to create and dispose of your context for my MVC3 app with multiple layers.  I started with EF4 and upgraded to EF5, and the default MSDN tutorials always seem to indicate working within using blocks, which seems particularly lousy - it seems to me that I have to pass the context object up and down the method chain.

I've done a fair bit of reading about context per request, repository patterns, unit of work patterns, etc, and it seems everyone is reinventing the wheel.

Are developers really sitting on a plethora of different EF implementations, or is there a common approach that I missed in a master tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to really remember is the underlying context is still a DbConnection.  It is recommend to wrap it in a `using` statement so you don't forget to dispose of it when you are done.

Other than that, it really depends on what you are doing.  Sometimes wrapping in a `using` statement is fine.  Other times you may need to keep a instance of it and keep using it, again, just remember to dispose of it when you are done.

I think the reposition pattern is fairly popular with abstracting the context so you can just call methods on the repository and then return the results from the context and keep it alive.

Comment: I can understand the need to wrap in a using statement, but the amount of code bloat is scary.  It seems to be the default Microsoft way, but it looks like so much work that I assume I read wrong.

Comment: @Savage You don't HAVE to use the `using` "pattern".  It is best to keep it simple like mentioned above.  EF is already an abstraction and adding more is redundant.  Just keep an instance of the context and make sure you dispose of it when you are done with the context.

Comment: Sure, but unless I'm mistaken, you have to share that instance up and down the method chain?

Comment: @Savage Perhaps you can give me an example, but if what I am thinking of is what you are talking about, it isn't uncommon to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There might have a few different ways to implement UoW and Repository pattern but one thing everyone agree with is that it's pretty useful because they create an abstraction level over the Context created by Entity Framework.

There are several reasons not to use directly the EF DBContext, two of them are preventing misuse and abstract complex features that should not be exposed to all the developers.

Now, concerning the implementation, I did not feel like reinventing the wheel when I came up using UoW and Repositories [that way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181290/decouple-unit-of-work-from-services-or-repo/15527444#15527444). Please have a look and tell me what you think! It's pretty straightforward.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Using UoW and Repository pattern on top of an ORM is really the last thing that "*everyone agrees with*". There are lots of different opinions.

Comment: Some good feedback from both, but what in your opinion is the most common efficient pattern?  There are so many implementations that I'm actually quite fed up with reading it all.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @Savage: "Most efficient"? Keep it simple! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tlMTJDKiug (Start at 50:22 of the video) The guy talking there is ayende (http://ayende.com/blog). Just to give you a viewpoint against too many layers, abstractions and against repositories. Unfortunately yet another viewpoint, because there is no "most common" pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I watched it - I know Ayende. I'm not looking for abstraction as much as simplification, and the "using" approach looks so cumbersome, but maybe I should bash away at it for a while and reconsider?

Comment: @Slauma thanks for your input. "_everyone agrees with_" is too simplistic, you’re right. It must be read "_every people that has decided to put UoW & repositories on their projects_". Thanks for sharing Ayende’s video, this is pretty interesting. I’m quite into getting things simplified, I love the KISS principle, but sometimes it just might not be the best choice. It depends on so many parameters like the size of your company, skills of people you're working with, the amount of legacy code you have to deal with... But that's another debate! :-)