# Entity Framework Unity of Work and Repository pattern

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I'm trying to implement UoW and Repository pattern, but I get error

*An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.*

I know that I get that error because I have two repositories which create two different DBContext, but I don't know why that happens.

Here is my code for UoW

```
 public  class UnitOfWorkRepositoryRepository : IUnitOfWorkRepository
{
    private readonly IDatabaseFactory _databaseFactory;
    private DatabaseContext _databaseContext;

    public UnitOfWorkRepositoryRepository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
    {
        _databaseFactory = databaseFactory;
    }

    public DatabaseContext Database
    {
        get { return _databaseContext ?? (_databaseContext = _databaseFactory.GetDatabaseContext()); }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _databaseContext.Save();
    }


}
```

And here sample Repository:

```
  private static readonly DatabaseFactory DatabaseFactory = new DatabaseFactory();
    private static readonly UnitOfWorkRepositoryRepository UnitOfWorkRepositoryRepository = new UnitOfWorkRepositoryRepository(DatabaseFactory);

    public User GetUserById(int id)
    {
        return UnitOfWorkRepositoryRepository.Database.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId.Equals(id));
    }
```

What's wrong ? how should I implement UoW

P.S.

I'm not getting any errors in this repository, but other one was too long, this one serves just as sample.

Comment: Why do you create multiple instances of the context class? Do you have a specific reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I think it is more descriptive, I have ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181290/decouple-unit-of-work-from-services-or-repo/15527444#15527444) where I describe a way to decoulple Uow from Repository.