# Unit of Work, Repository, Injection, using block

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, ninject, unit-of-work

### Intro

After having read multiple articles on how to implement a Unit of Work and keeping in mind testability (unit testing), I can see the following in some of what I have read:

- Interfaces: IRepository, IUnitOfWork. IRepository can be (probably would be) a generic like `IRepository<TEntity>`.
- There is a coupling between IRepository and IUnitOfWork. In some examples, you can see a dependency in IRepository on IUnitOfWork. You would also see, multiple IRepository properties in a concrete UnitOfWork
- In multiple examples near the end you can see a usage example like this:

  ```
  using(var uow = new UnitOfWork()) {
  //some work here, maybe accessing member repositories in uow like:
  //var item = uow.Repository1.GetById(1);
  //item.SomeModifyingOperation();
  uow.Save();
  }
  ```

### Questions/Observations

- Is such a usage testable? It is obviously dependent on a concrete implementation of UnitOfWork.
- Is such an example something that is expected to **not** be covered by our unit tests?
- If it is to be tested then how would the code change? would we have the unit of work injected in the constructor like `ctor(IUnitOfWork uow){this.uow = uow;}` and then use it like this: `this.uow.Save();`?
- If we go that path then we cannot utilize the using statement and the automatic disposing of uow. We would be doing manually something like `uow.Dispose();`.
- Can we (ex: Ninject) depend on the DI container to handle the disposing for us per web request (MVC)? If yes, how do we do it (Ninject) and is it an efficient approach from a design POV?
- Would you consider that a unit of work would give access to all repositories in the domain (if UnitOfWork was exposing repositories) and thus we only have one concrete implementation of IUnitOfWork?
- Is it better to keep IUnitOfWork as simple as containing just a Save() method signature or have it include IRepository properties or maybe a generic method signature like `IRepository GetRepository<TEntity>();`?

### References

- http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application
- [Decouple unit of work from services or repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181290/decouple-unit-of-work-from-services-or-repo/15527444#15527444)
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31822/unit-of-work-and-repository-design-pattern-implementation/31833#31833?newreg=c38ed8eac7b549728ae8f82b965fff09

Comment: I would use `IRepository.Save<T>` instead of `IRepository<T>.Save()`. Save you the hassle of creating multiple repositories in case you are accessing mutliple entitites.

Answer (score 3):

Create a IUnitOfWorkFactory that is injected via DI:

```
public interface IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    IUnitOfWork Create();
}

public class UnitOfWorkFactory : IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    public IUnitOfWork Create()
    {
        return new UnitOfWork();
    }
}
```

Then in your consumer you inject UnitOfWorkFactory:

```
public MyController(IUnitOfWorkFactory workFactory)
{
    this.workFactory = workFactory;
}

public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    using(var uow = workFactory.Create())
    {
        //do work
    }
}
```

This way you get the best from both worlds. You get your objects injected - helps with testability. And you get your UOW automatically disposed when needed.

By the way, this is example from [the DI book](http://www.manning.com/seemann/) worth reading for these patterns.

**EDIT**: [This chapter from DI book](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/csharp/9781935182504/object-lifetime/ch08lev1sec2) is talking about Disposable objects